# Can kubernetes cluster formed from mix of AWS nodes, Azure nodes, VMWare nodes

Tags: kubernetes

Is HA across multiple cloud providers i.e ONE kubernetes cluster from mix of Azure nodes, AWS nodes, VMware nodes. (Consider all have same OS image)

- If so how dynamic provisioning works.
- Can Kubernetes CSI (container storage interface) help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work very well. The cloud provider needs to be set on the apiserver & controller-manager and you can't run multiple copies of those in different configurations.

Now if you don't need a cloud provider, as in you are just using these as generic VMs, you will not have access to cloud storage via the kubernetes api. Otherwise it's workable but is still not a great setup. This would essentially be a cross region cluster which is not a supported use case. You are meant  to use 1 cluster per region and arrange for LB somehow (yes, this is the tricky bit).